# How to transform secondary y axis and scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have the following plot in `ggplot2` but I'm not too happy with how the secondary y axis is scaled cause the grey line looks fairly flat.

I would prefer to create a scale for the secondary y axis and the grey line with a range of only 1.75 to 2.25 so that I can see the movements a bit better. Any advice on how to do this?

```
library(tidyverse)

reserves_level <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18291, 18321, 18351, 18382, 
18412, 18443, 18473, 18504, 18535, 18565, 18596, 18626, 18657, 
18291, 18321, 18351, 18382, 18412, 18443, 18473, 18504, 18535, 
18565, 18596, 18626, 18657), class = "Date"), Key = c("Reserves (NAD)", 
"Reserves (NAD)", "Reserves (NAD)", "Reserves (NAD)", "Reserves (NAD)", 
"Reserves (NAD)", "Reserves (NAD)", "Reserves (NAD)", "Reserves (NAD)", 
"Reserves (NAD)", "Reserves (NAD)", "Reserves (NAD)", "Reserves (NAD)", 
"Reserves (USD)", "Reserves (USD)", "Reserves (USD)", "Reserves (USD)", 
"Reserves (USD)", "Reserves (USD)", "Reserves (USD)", "Reserves (USD)", 
"Reserves (USD)", "Reserves (USD)", "Reserves (USD)", "Reserves (USD)", 
"Reserves (USD)"), Value = c(30.96107351507, 32.16872169411, 
32.97394333811, 35.6594389906, 32.944455576, 31.75897192528, 
35.3995709836, 33.3870647566, 32.66579275848, 34.35383925875, 
29.92587, 31.7517, 33.35816, 2.06261398712043, 2.05295138288458, 
1.84674175243683, 1.92451004045528, 1.87739090357876, 1.83355302380232, 
2.08125035179437, 1.97135496109494, 1.95207290341642, 2.11488932754343, 
1.94197, 2.10318, 2.20185)), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = subset(reserves_level, Key %in% c("Reserves (NAD)")),
           mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = Key),
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(data = subset(reserves_level, Key == "Reserves (USD)"),
            mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Value*15, group = Key, color = Key),
            size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#7c3042','#c7af76')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('grey')) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis= sec_axis(~./15, name="Reserves (USD)", breaks = seq(0,2.5, by = 0.25)))
```

[image]

Comment: Add something like `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(25, 40))`. However, be aware that this type of chart is not recommended: https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/

Comment: This is a highly discussed issue. You should go through this site: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales>. Here you will find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this can help you

```
ylim.p <- c(0, 30)   
ylim.s <- c(1.75, 2.25)    

b <- diff(ylim.p)/diff(ylim.s)
a <- b*(ylim.p[1] - ylim.s[1])

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = subset(reserves_level, Key %in% c("Reserves (NAD)")),
           mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = Key),
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(data = subset(reserves_level, Key == "Reserves (USD)"),
            mapping = aes(x = Date, y = (Value*b)+a, group = Key, color = Key),
            size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#7c3042','#c7af76')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('grey')) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis= sec_axis(~(. - a)/b, name="Reserves (USD)", breaks = seq(1.75,2.5, by = 0.25)))
```